# x509 Client Authentication from Weblogic server towards IIS SSL service (Failed to load server trusted CAs java.lang.NullPointerException)

Tags: java, iis, ssl, weblogic

I have a need to access an webservice endpoint which is two-way SSL enabled and it is also SSL authenticated. Which means if I as a client have to invoke, it should authenticate my certificate. So in order to make this work from my IE browser, I created a private key using OpenSSL and a self signed certificate and then sent this self-signed certificate to external partner who hosts this webservice so as they can authenticate me via my certificate when I send requests to them. And then I created a .pfx file that used my self-signed certificate and private key and then I installed this pfx file on IE and then my IE was able to invoke this WS endpoint.

Now, I want to use my weblogic server to invoke this service, and I followed instructions at 
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/grid/pfx-pem-certificate-formats-092744.html

And, after everything is done, I am seeing this error in weblogic logs

```
<Nov 12, 2014 3:25:23 AM UTC> <Notice> <Security> <BEA-090171> <Loading the identity certificate and private key 
stored under the alias mykey from the jks keystore file /opt/oracle/domains11.1.1.6/iip_01_soa_domain/myIdentityKeystore.jks.> 
<Nov 12, 2014 3:25:23 AM UTC> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <Failed to load server trusted CAs 
java.lang.NullPointerException 
at weblogic.security.utils.SSLContextManager.getRealmName(SSLContextManager.java:736)
```

Any idea what is wrong? The target server is running in IIS server and it uses a self signed certificate. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Is `/opt/oracle/domains11.1.1.6/iip_01_soa_domain/myIdentityKeystore.jks` present on every host and are the permissions correct?

The next logging line I would expect to see is something like:

```
Loading trusted certificates from the JKS keystore file /path/to/cacerts.jks.
```

So it seems like your CA is not set up for your server (if the identity keystore is indeed available). In the admin console have you set up the CA for your server by editing this field:

```
Servers -> <server name> -> Configuration -> Keystores -> Custom Trust Keystore
```

Is the keystore type also set to JKS?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply and sorry that I noticed it a bit late. The .jks file is available there and I don't see next logging line as mentioned by you. I have set keystore type to JKS and my client certificate is a self signed certificate.